# add audio in html without <audio> element (preferebly js)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm wondering if we can make audio in html without the  tag. perhaps we could have buttons for play and pause but still I don't know how to control volume, etc. I searched up other websites, And couldn't find the answer.
thanks,
Smit

Comment: Use [`new Audio()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement). You can use the resulting object as an [`Audio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) element.

Comment: If you don't want to use the audio tag because of browser compatibility (you didn't specify a reason) when Audio API in JS probably won't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript to dynamically edit the attributes of audio.

Here is a list of functions:

```
myaudio.play(); - This will play the music.
myaudio.pause(); - This will stop the music.
myaudio.duration; - Returns the length of the music track.
myaudio.currentTime = 0; - This will rewind the audio to the beginning.
myaudio.loop = true; - This will make the audio track loop.
myaudio.muted = true; - This will mute the track
```

Like this there are many functions, please go through the documentation at W3C.

Comment: Thanks! the list of functions really helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can use  tag to add the audio in your website. It comes with the Controls attribute as well.

This website might be helpful for you:
http://www.webreference.com/js/column20/control.html